# MySQL select based on two different columns

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table (coming from a join so no natural PK) with two columns that are independent:

```
A    B
------
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    a
2    b
```

In Java I have an array of elements that contain both values, say (1,b) and (2, a).

How do I select all the relevant values?

Of course, I could do it in two different selects:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A = 1 and B = b;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A = 2 and B = a;
```

Which in Hibernate would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A = :a and B = :b
```

Then I would repeat the query for all inputs.

Of course, I **cannot** do:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where A in (1, 2) and B in (a, b)
```

since it will return 4 columns.

Is it possible to query that in only one parametric query, with Java and Hibernate that does not depend on the input?

I'll be receiving a long array so writing N queries is not an option, nor writing by hand a query that depends on the input.

For example, if I was interested in one column, the query in hibernate would be:

```
SELECT * from my_table where A in (:my_array)
```

PS.
In Postgres this could be achieved with `jsonb_to_recordset` which would convert an array of elements to a table wit a row per element, then joining with `my_table`, it would only have 1 parameter which would be the array.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,'b'), (2,'a'))`

Comment: @Akina is it possible to pass (1, 'b'), (2, 'a') as parameter in mysql with hibernate? that would be great

Comment: *In Postgres this could be achieved with jsonb_to_recordset which would convert an array of elements to a table wit a row per element, then joining with my_table.* If your MySQL version is recent enough (8.0.4 and later) you may use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). *is it possible to pass (1, 'b'), (2, 'a') as parameter in mysql with hibernate?* The only info which I know about Hibernate - it exists...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (A = 1 AND B = b) OR (A = 2 AND B = a);
```

Comment: Your answer is in fact correct for the question as it was stated, but it is not what I'm looking for. I've updated the question. I want a parametric query in Hibernate that does not depend on the input. For example, if using only one column that is correct